# How to capture gatling.io https / wss calls through fiddler?

Tags: scala-gatling

I'm running gatling.io to load test my server, but I would like to be able to view the calls so I can debug portions of the script.  I know I can have it write all the logs to the console, but viewing through fiddler is nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for a few hours until I found a solution.  This is by far the easiest.  Just modify your gatling.io's scala script's http configuration object to use fiddler's proxy.

Just like this:

```
val httpConf = http
  .proxy(
    Proxy("127.0.0.1", 8888)
      .httpsPort(8888)
  )
```